# incorrect syntax near ';'

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2016 I miss this error in this query:

```
 select count(*) 
 from (select count(*), clave 
       from products 
       where state = 1 
       group by key 
       having count(*) > 1 );
```

I have tried to copy and paste the query in a note pad in case some invalid character or space has been inserted.

Comment: You need an alias on the subquery.

Comment: @paparazzo Given the OP's explicit statement that the query was copied and pasted *specifically* to avoid accidentally introducing errors, reformatting the query while leaving that statement intact seems inappropriate to me.

Comment: @hvd A line break does not change a query.

Comment: @paparazzo But it's no longer copied and pasted, while the question still claims it is.

Answer (score 2):

You need alias :

```
select count(*) 
from (select count(*)
      from products 
      where [state] = 1 
      group by [key]
      having count(*) > 1 
     ) t; -- t alias
```

Considering to use only words or identifiers which have not reserved by SQL Server, such as `key` (especially in your case) & [many more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Second thing when you include `group by` clause with your query you should be care about `select` statement with expressions/columns (which are available in `group by` clause or the expression/column which are not in group by clause you should include aggregate function to that column/expression.)

Comment: @Yogesh Sharma you can not write [column] in query this way it gives error of Unexpected character.

Answer (score -1):

'Key' is a reserve word so you can not use it so you should rename it and your result is a table so you should give it an alias.
Try something like
`

```
select count(*) 
 from (select count(*), clave 
       from products 
       where state = 1 
       group by key1 
       having count(*) > 1 ) AS product_alias;
```

'